# Foundation 5 Dropdown Menu Misalign in scrollable table row

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember.js, zurb-foundation-5

I would like to add a dropdown button inside a scrollable table row. I am able to get the dropdown working inside a scrollable table row. However, when you scroll **inside** the table row, the dropdown menu will misalign.

Here are some screenshots to  elaborate.

1. Initial state, when **`Dropdown Button 1`** is clicked.
   [image: Initial state, when **<code>Dropdown Button 1</code>** is clicked]
2. When you scroll the page **outside** of the table, it works fine.
   [image]
3. When you scroll the page **inside** the table row, the dropdown menu **misalign**.
   [image]

Please refer to this example in jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/kuhavenaya/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Click on the **`Dropdown Button 1`**, dropdown menu will show up.

- Try scrolling **inside** the table row and you will see that the dropdown menu will **misalign**.
- But, when you scroll **outside** of the table, it will **work fine**.

Any help and suggestion to solve this issue is much appreciated. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the above implementation is that the dropdown menu is relative to the window body and not the dropdown menu container.

Therefore, the solution is to have a `position: relative` encapsulating the dropdown button.

Here is a working [example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/tunirihego/edit?html,js,output) that fixes the dropdown menu misalign issue.

Thanks~